# Android: It is Possible Send SMS to email without Internet and Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, excel, sms

Im just wondering, it is possible send sms to gmail without internet and action send like gmail. i want is when user input the data . then click the "SEND" button
it will automatically send. skip the action using like GMAIL,etc.

then when receive data from gmail, it will automatically generated/inserted from my excel.

I need is SMS only consume to send data, not INTERNET.

Comment: SMS and GMAIL are not compatible. You can't send SMS to Gmail. SMS is sent via mobile network to the **Phone Number**. Gmail is an **Email client/server**

Answer (score 0):

You cant sorry:(

Email work on the internet that's the whole point :P

You could do it if your on an Intranet having your own email network, but that wont work with gmail because you have to talk to that guy who isn't really present there, like making a call on a landline unless there is a connection between the two of you, you cant make the call :)

Comment: i think in other words, i want customize MMS (Multimedia Message)